# Rails 3 - Model related to current user in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, model-view-controller, relationship

We assume an authentication system is setup and we have access to a variable `current_user`, e.g.: using the Devise gem.

We have two models, `User` and `Thing`, `User has one Thing`.
In the controller, what's the best practise in order to get the right Thing to create/delete if we assume that a `User` can only create/delete his own `Thing`.

Eg for create action.

OPTION 1 (standard) :

```
@thing = Thing.new(params[:thing])
@thing.save
```

And we set the user_id in the view.

OPTION 2 :

```
@thing = current_user.create_thing
```

And we don't bother about setting the user_id in the view.

Both works but I would like to know if one must be avoid or is better and why.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally think the second option is better because (as you say) you don't have to mess around with a user_id (neither in the view nor specifically within the controller).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the same, I'm now sure about it!

Answer (score 2):

The first option is only useful if you want to allow users to set things for other users than themselves. If you don't want to allow this, the first option even introduces a possible vulnerability. Malicious users can try exploiting the `user_id` field in the view. So, assuming users can only set their own things: definitely option 2.

Comment: Yes but you're basically saying the same except the vulnerability information which is another topic for me :) I use authorisation for that problem. Wish I could vote for both of you!

Comment: @AlrickDeillon, you asked which is better and **why**. moritz doesn't give any reason (besides the obvious), so I don't think my answer is basically the same. Anyway, I am not trying to convince you to change the accepted answer (please don't). I was just kidding because you said "oldest" and not "best".

Comment: I agree, I will think better next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise gem, Its better to play with current_user. This will be more secured than passing users id.